# Lambda Coding node.JS trying to send message to SQS

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, lambda

I have been trying to get this action to work.  i am able to send a message to SQS on my own when i use the inline editor.  and i am able to use my uploaded code with the node-mysql to do a database insert however i can not get to two to work together.  currently i get no output when running my code here is what i am running

```
console.log('Loading function');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });
var QUEUE_URL = 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/1234/dev-upload-test';
var sqs = new AWS.SQS({region:'eu-east-1'}); 


exports.handler = function (event, context) {
  var srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
  var srcKey = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));

  var company = 123;
  var user = 321;
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : '10.0.1.22', //lamdba has access to this VPC
    user     : 'username',
    password : 'password',
    database : 'development',
  });
  connection.connect(function(err) {
    if(err){
      console.log('Error connecting to Db');
      return;
    }
    console.log('Connection established');
  });
  var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO messages (created_at, processing) VALUES (now(),1)', function(err,results){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(results.insertId);
    console.log('trying to send message');

    var msg = { payload: srcBucket,srcKey };
    var sqsParams = {
      MessageBody: JSON.stringify(msg),
      QueueUrl: 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/1234/dev-upload-test'
    };
    console.log(sqsParams)

    var sqsdata = sqs.sendMessage(sqsParams, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('ERR', err);
      }
      console.log(data);
    });
    console.log('message sent')
  });
  context.succeed('Exit');
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to put `context.succeed('Exit');` inside the `sqs.sendMessage` callback. Right now your Lambda function is queuing up a bunch of asynchronous work, but then you exit synchronously at the end of the handler function before any of it has finished.